# Magento loading Model from wrong directory

Tags: model

I'm trying to load a model with: `Mage::getModel('OnePica_AvaTax/AvaTax_Estimate')` but Magento errors with `Warning: include(Mage\OnePica\AvaTax\Model\AvaTax\Estimate.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`, when this model is in the Community folder, not the Core folder... `Mage` shouldn't be there at all.

I know I've dealt with this in the past, but I can't remember what the correct way to do this is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The factory pattern `Mage::getModel` takes a specific input. This follows the form of `[module]/path_to_class`.

In the case of Avatax, the [model] is defined as `avatax`:

```
#file: app/code/community/Onepica/Avatax/etc/config.xml
//...
<global>
    <models>
        <avatax>
            <class>OnePica_AvaTax_Model</class>
        </avatax>
//....
```

So you will load the model with this:

```
Mage::getModel('avatax/avatax_estimate');
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Was about to say it didn't work, but case sensitivity caught me!